# Trouble getting order of Image Bitmap layers in Android correct

Tags: java, opencv, android

I have a piece of code that compares to images and places a marker on the difference. So far it works well, except the latest marker layer that is added always shows underneath all the older markers. I have the latest one as a yellow color and the older ones as red. When the difference is close to one of the red markers, the yellow marker shows behind those ones.

Is there anyone that can help me get the yellow (Latest marker) to appear on top?

This is my code so far:

```
public class CheckmarkActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZoomLayout.OnZoomableLayoutClickEventListener  {

    TextView tv;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout_work;
    ImageView imageViewtest;
    Bitmap prevBmp = null;
    Timer t;
    TimerTask task;
    int time = 100;

    float image_Width;
    float image_Height;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkmark);
        if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet)) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }

        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

        relativeLayout_work = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_work);
        imageViewtest = findViewById(R.id.imageViewtest);

        prevBmp = ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.getLastScreenShot();

        if (prevBmp == null || ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot == null) {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }

        startTimer();

   }

   // image compare
   class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String>
   {
       String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
       PointF p;
       Bitmap test_3;
       protected void onPreExecute (){
           super.onPreExecute();
           Log.d(TAG + " PreExceute","On pre Exceute......");
       }

       protected String doInBackground(Object...arg0) {

           test_3 = ImageHelper.findDifference(CheckmarkActivity.this, prevBmp, ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot);

           p = ImageHelper.findShot(test_3);
           time = 1;

           return "You are at PostExecute";
       }

       protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...a){
           super.onProgressUpdate(a);
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
           addImageToImageview();

           PointF np = Session.convertPointBitmap2View(p, relativeLayout_work, ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot);
           tv.setX(np.x - tv.getWidth() / 2);
           tv.setY(np.y - tv.getHeight() / 2);

           tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//           imageViewtest.setImageBitmap(test_3);
       }
   }

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i("OpenCV", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    new TestAsync().execute();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d("OpenCV", "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d("OpenCV", "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }


    public static int[] getBitmapOffset(ImageView img,  Boolean includeLayout) {
        int[] offset = new int[2];
        float[] values = new float[9];

        Matrix m = img.getImageMatrix();
        m.getValues(values);

        offset[0] = (int) values[5];
        offset[1] = (int) values[2];

        if (includeLayout) {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();
            int paddingTop = (int) (img.getPaddingTop() );
            int paddingLeft = (int) (img.getPaddingLeft() );

            offset[0] += paddingTop + lp.topMargin;
            offset[1] += paddingLeft + lp.leftMargin;
        }
        return offset;
    }

    public static int[] getBitmapPositionInsideImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        int[] ret = new int[4];

        if (imageView == null || imageView.getDrawable() == null)
            return ret;

        // Get image dimensions
        // Get image matrix values and place them in an array
        float[] f = new float[9];
        imageView.getImageMatrix().getValues(f);

        // Extract the scale values using the constants (if aspect ratio maintained, scaleX == scaleY)
        final float scaleX = f[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        final float scaleY = f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

        // Get the drawable (could also get the bitmap behind the drawable and getWidth/getHeight)
        final Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
        final int origW = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int origH = d.getIntrinsicHeight();

        // Calculate the actual dimensions
        final int actW = Math.round(origW * scaleX);
        final int actH = Math.round(origH * scaleY);

        ret[2] = actW;
        ret[3] = actH;

        // Get image position
        // We assume that the image is centered into ImageView
        int imgViewW = imageView.getWidth();
        int imgViewH = imageView.getHeight();

        int top = (int) (imgViewH - actH)/2;
        int left = (int) (imgViewW - actW)/2;

        ret[0] = left;
        ret[1] = top;

        return ret;
    }
    private void addImageToImageview(){

        if (ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot != null) {

            imageViewtest.setImageBitmap(ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot);
            Log.d("width", String.valueOf(imageViewtest.getWidth()));
        }

        Resources r = getResources();
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, r.getDisplayMetrics());

        for (int i = 0; i < ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.getShotCount(); i++) {
            PointF p = ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.getPoint(i);
            TextView t = new TextView(this);
            t.setText("" + (i + 1));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)px, (int)px);
            relativeLayout_work.addView(t);
            t.setLayoutParams(param);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
            p = Session.convertPointBitmap2View(p, relativeLayout_work, ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot);
            t.setX(p.x);
            t.setY(p.y);
            t.setTag(10000 + i);
        }
    }

    public void onConfirm(View v){
        View vv = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_work);
        PointF bp = Session.convertPointView2Bitmap(new PointF(tv.getX(), tv.getY()), relativeLayout_work, ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot);
        ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.addNewShot(ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot, bp);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    public void onCancel(View v){
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

        finish();

    }


    @Override
    public void OnContentClickEvent(int action, float xR, float yR) {
        int[] offset = new int[2];
        int[] rect = new int[4];
        offset = this.getBitmapOffset(imageViewtest, false);
        int original_width = imageViewtest.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        int original_height = imageViewtest.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        rect = getBitmapPositionInsideImageView(imageViewtest);
        Log.i("OffsetY", String.valueOf(offset[0]));
        Log.i("OffsetX", String.valueOf(offset[1]));
        Log.i( "0", String.valueOf(rect[0]));
        Log.i( "1", String.valueOf(rect[1]));
        Log.i( "2", String.valueOf(rect[2]));
        Log.i( "3", String.valueOf(rect[3]));

        if (xR > rect[0] && xR < rect[0] + rect[2] && yR > rect[1] && yR < rect[1] + rect[3]) {
            tv.setX(xR - tv.getWidth() / 2);
            tv.setY(yR - tv.getHeight() / 2);
        }


//        tv.setX(xR - tv.getWidth() / 2);
//        tv.setY(yR - tv.getHeight() / 2);

    }

    public void onMoveButtonPressed(View v) {
        ImageButton b = (ImageButton)v;

        int mId = b.getId();

        switch (mId) {
            case R.id.imageButtonL:
                tv.setX(tv.getX() - 1);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButtonR:
                tv.setX(tv.getX() + 1);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButtonD:
                tv.setY(tv.getY() + 1);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButtonU:
                tv.setY(tv.getY() - 1);
                break;
        }

    }

    //timer change image
    public void startTimer(){
        t = new Timer();
        task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (time == 1){
                            imageViewtest.setImageBitmap(ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot);
//                            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            tv.setText("" + (ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.getShotCount() + 1));
                            t.cancel();
                            return;
                        }
                        if (time % 2 == 0) {
                            imageViewtest.setImageBitmap(prevBmp);
                        }
                        else if(time % 2 == 1){
                           imageViewtest.setImageBitmap(ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot);
                        }
                        time --;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 500);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the z-order of the child view with `addView()` function.

```
void addView (View child, int index)
```

ex)

```
private void addImageToImageview(){

    if (ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot != null) {

        imageViewtest.setImageBitmap(ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot);
        Log.d("width", String.valueOf(imageViewtest.getWidth()));
    }

    Resources r = getResources();
    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, r.getDisplayMetrics());

    int currChildrenCount = relativeLayout_work.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.getShotCount(); i++) {
        PointF p = ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.getPoint(i);
        TextView t = new TextView(this);
        t.setText("" + (i + 1));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)px, (int)px);
        relativeLayout_work.addView(t, currChildrenCount+i);   // You can control the order like this
        t.setLayoutParams(param);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
        p = Session.convertPointBitmap2View(p, relativeLayout_work, ViewcontrollerActivity.workSession.workScreenShot);
        t.setX(p.x);
        t.setY(p.y);
        t.setTag(10000 + i);
    }
}
```